# When I log into my PC via GoToMyPc, all the other computers in my house lose connectivity

Tags: internet, home-networking, remote-control

When I log into my home PC through GoToMyPC from work, the computers in my home lose Internet connectivity.

Has anyone had this issue before or has some insight into this?

Comment: More info pls.  Home router? model?  Also, by "lose internet connectivity", what exactly happens?  Do applications, browsing, etc slow to a crawl, or do the other computers' network adapters become disconnected?

Comment: Alright here is the info.  My wireless router a LINKSYS WRT54GV8 and i have one home desktop pc that is connected via an ethernet cable and the other laptops are connected via wireless.

Comment: When connection is established via GoToMyPC to the desktop PC, the laptops that are connected wirelessly lose the ability to browse the internet.  Once the GoToMyPC connection is terminated, internet traffic is restored to the other wirelessly connected computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your router is misbehaving when GoToMyPC is active.  This is likely just something screwy with the router firmware, when it detects a certain type of packet incoming it's going haywire and disabling the wireless network.

You can try [upgrading the firmware](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/support/WRT54G/download) on it -- make sure you get the right version for your device; they list different files for v8.0, v8.1, and v8.2.

If that doesn't fix the problem, you can

1. try a third-party firmware (DD-WRT, OpenWRT, Tomato) if your device is supported.
2. try a different router (different model linksys, even a different version WRT54G, may not have the same problem).

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds like a good solution, i'll give it a shot and see what happens.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using internet connection sharing from that PC? GoToMyPC may be affecting that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also think that GoToMyPC may be affecting. I use [pc file transfer](http://www.pc-file-transfer.com/). I have several computers set up with this program and it works good. I don't have problems with this remote application tool, ever.